# Adding JS Files - Webpack - Static Site Boilerplate

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm currently learning webpack to improve my static site building process. I'm using a boilerplate called [Static site boilerplate](http://staticsiteboilerplate.com/).

I have an issue with it since i'm not on point with webpack. At start, there is only one `.js` file in the `javascripts` folder called `scripts.js`. What i'd like to do is add multiple files in this `javascripts`folder and join them into one file only, the `scripts.js` (like in Sass).

How can i do this?

Here is the webpack.config.js file :

```
const path = require('path');

const config = require('./site.config');
const loaders = require('./webpack.loaders');
const plugins = require('./webpack.plugins');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(config.root, config.paths.src),
  entry: [
    path.join(config.root, config.paths.src, 'javascripts/scripts.js'),
    path.join(config.root, config.paths.src, 'stylesheets/styles.scss'),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(config.root, config.paths.dist),
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
  },
  mode: ['production', 'development'].includes(config.env) ? config.env : 'development',
  devtool: config.env === 'production' ? 'hidden-source-map' : 'cheap-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(config.root, config.paths.src),
    watchContentBase: true,
    hot: true,
    open: true,
    port: config.port,
    host: config.dev_host,
  },
  module: {
    rules: loaders,
  },
  plugins,
};
```

And [here is the github repo](https://github.com/ericalli/static-site-boilerplate) to see the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

anything you import in an entry point file will be bundled by webpack into your final bundle, so in your entry JS file you can just import or require your other JS modules.  you can even import your SCSS there and not have the SCSS entry point.  have you been through the guides?  https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/

for instance, in a JS entry point:

```
import '../css/main.scss'; // scss
import createAside from './createAside'; // JS function
import projects from './projects'; // JS data
import links from './links';
```

these will all be processed and bundled together in accordance with your config